# Why is it not possible to unpack lists inside a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, iterable-unpacking

Starred expressions raise `SyntaxError` when used in list or generator comprehension.

I'm curious about the reason behind this; is it an implementation choice or there are technical constraints that would prevent this operation?

I've found a lot about the contexts that don't allow for unpacking iterables but nothing about why.

Example:

```
lis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
listcomp = [*lis for i in range(3)]
```

I thought maybe I could use this to get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` as a result, but it raises

> SyntaxError("Iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension")

Comment: What, *exactly* do you mean?

Comment: I think he is trying to say if ```a``` is a list of lists, then ```[*l for l in a]``` raises a syntax error. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Do you mean something like `[*sub for sub in some_iterable]`, which would be equivalent to `[s for sub in some_iterable for s in sub]`? I guess, because `*sub` isn't really an expression on its own, and that part of a list comprehension accepts expressions. It would be a special case to accept something else. Not *impossible*, but the answer to *why* is probably "not worth the trouble of implementing and making some special case for the grammar"

Comment: As@juanpa.arrivillaga stated, ```listcomp = [*lis for i in range(5)]``` is as good as ```listcomp = [for i in range(5) for j in list]```

Comment: It *might* be allowed, in theory, someday. `[*(1,2,3)]` used to be a syntax error, but now evaluates to `[1,2,3]`. In the meantime, you might want to look at `itertools.chain` for flattening lists.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh ok so it's an implementation choice. Yes I can see why it would be more of a syntactic sugar than an actual functionality. Just tought it would save a lot of nested comps for example. Thank you for explaining though

Comment: "*Why* is X not possible" is not a good question for Stack Overflow, imo. The answer is almost certainly going to be "the devs did not have time to implement it, or considered it unnecessary".

Comment: @jfaccioni Well not necessarily... think about the *'infamous'* GIL. Why Cpp-like multithreading is not possible in Python is a fairly interesting question and it has nothing to do with implementation times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was proposed in [PEP 448 -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#variations) but ultimately not accepted due to concerns about readability:

> Earlier iterations of this PEP allowed unpacking operators inside list, set, and dictionary comprehensions as a flattening operator over iterables of containers: [...]
> This was met with a mix of strong concerns about readability and mild support. In order not to disadvantage the less controversial aspects of the PEP, this was not accepted with the rest of the proposal.

Notably, the possibility to add this at a later point has not been ruled out.

> This PEP does not include unpacking operators inside list, set and dictionary comprehensions although this has not been ruled out for future proposals.

Comment: Oh so they did indeed consider it. That's interesting to know!